# keepalived not working on 20.04

Tags: networking, server

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I have setup keepalived with 3 machines and one VIP. I can see keepalived is adding and removing the VIP from the master/slave as expected.  However, none of my ubuntu boxes 'bind' to this VIP.  I can ping the VIP (confirm the icmp packets hit the proper box/master) but no response is given.  I have added  "net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1" to /etc/sysctl.conf.  Confirmed with:

cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_nonlocal_bind
1

I have ran: iptables --flush

I have tried: modprobe ip_vs

I can add an IP(the VIP address for testing) to eth0 via: ip address add 192.168.1.131/24 dev eth0
and ping this IP just fine. (this was just for testing and has been removed)

I see the virtual IP bound to the nic via keepalived:

```
inet 192.168.1.70/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
   valid_lft 85701sec preferred_lft 85701sec
inet 192.168.1.131/32 scope global eth0  <-------
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, I can not ping it or reach any services via this VIP. The ip_nonlocal_bind functionality seems broken somehow. Perhaps a kernel module is missing?

Note - these are Ubuntu VM's running on Xen. I have CentOs7 VM's working properly with keepalived on the same hypervisor.

Answer (score 5):

I am a maintainer of keepalived, and it is I who has implemented vrrp_strict.

First of all I am sorry you have had trouble when upgrading the version of keepalived you are using, and the time you have consequently lost.

We do try to maintain backward compatibility with old configuration supported by older versions of keepalived, but sometimes that is not always possible, especially if the code is not working in accordance with the documentation, or if a bug fix requires a slight change in functionality.

As the keepalived.conf(5) man page says, vrrp_strict is intended to enforce strict VRRP protocol compliance. When it was initially implemented it did not check every aspect of configuration options which did not comply with the RFCs, but as versions have moved on that enforcement has improved. This is to help configure keepalived when interworking with a strictly conforming VRRP implementation.

In this case, vrrp_strict was specified, but keepalived v1.3.5 did not apply a check for accept mode. That check was subsequently added, since VRRPv2 does not support accept_mode.

The reason there was no error logged was that as far as keepalived was concerned there was no error; it was simply applying the default for a parameter (accept/no_accept) that was not specified. Had accept been configured, keepalived would have logged: "(VI_1) warning - accept mode for VRRP version 2 does not comply with RFC3768 - resetting".

The RFCs envisage VRRP being used on IP routers, with additional routers being able to backup the main router, and that the VIPs are addresses that naturally belong to the main router, but that backup routers will support for routeing purposes in the event that the main router is not available. It therefore has the concept that only the main router should be addressable on any of the VIPs, since they are the main router's own IP addresses, but the backup routers should not be addressable via the VIPs. The only purpose the VIPs are configured on backup routers (when they become master) is so that they can respond to ARP requests so that end stations can send packets to their IP address for onward forwarding. This is why vrrp_strict sets no_accept mode as the default if the priority of the VRRP instance is not 255.

Given the distros you have indicated you have been using, I am assuming that you have moved from v1.3.5 to v2.0.19 (or v2.2.21 if using the keepalived snap).

Unfortunately I cannot see how we could have done this better. vrrp_strict had been configured, and keepalived v1.3.5 had not fully implemented that; over time the implementation of vrrp_strict has improved to better meet what the man page states it does.

If there are any suggestions regarding how this sort of thing can be done better, we would be very happen to consider them.

I will update the keepalived.conf(5) man page to better document the checks that are made when vrrp_strict, and it will now say the following:

```
    # Enforce strict VRRP protocol compliance. This currently includes 
    #  enforcing the following. Please note that other checks may be
    #  added in the future if they are found to be missing:
    #   0 VIPs not allowed
    #   unicast peers not allowed
    #   IPv6 addresses not allowed in VRRP version 2
    #   First IPv6 VIP is not link local
    #   State MASTER can be configured if and only if priority is 255
    #   Authentication is not supported
    #   Preempt delay is not supported
    #   Accept mode cannot be set for VRRPv2
    #   If accept/no accept is not specified, accept is set if priority
    #    is 255 aand cleared otherwise
    #   Gratuitous ARP repeats cannot be enabled
    #   Cannot clear lower_prio_no_advert
    #   Cannot set higher_prio_send_advert
    #   Cannot use vmac_xmit_base
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to this. This helped me resolve a very similar (if not the exact same) issue as the OPs. With this answer, I was able to correct my configuration and achieve the desired result. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Update - I found the bug/solution.  The config I used was copied from an older version of keepalived (the one used on the centOs7 VM's). In the global section one line breaks things:

```
global_defs {
   notification_email {
     xxxx@nana.com
   }
   notification_email_from keepalive@xxxx.com
   smtp_server smtp.gmail.com
   smtp_connect_timeout 30

   router_id LVS_DEVEL
   vrrp_skip_check_adv_addr
#   vrrp_strict <-----------THIS MO FO!
   vrrp_garp_interval 0
   vrrp_gna_interval 0
}
```

The sad part here is all the time lost finding this. Note there was nothing screaming "ERROR" in the system logs:

```
 keepalived.service - Keepalive Daemon (LVS and VRRP)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/keepalived.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-02-01 17:21:18 UTC; 17s ago
   Main PID: 13352 (keepalived)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 4677)
     Memory: 1.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/keepalived.service
             ├─13352 /usr/sbin/keepalived --dont-fork
             └─13361 /usr/sbin/keepalived --dont-fork

Feb 01 17:21:18 ubuntu4 Keepalived_vrrp[13361]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Feb 01 17:21:18 ubuntu4 Keepalived_vrrp[13361]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Feb 01 17:21:18 ubuntu4 Keepalived_vrrp[13361]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Feb 01 17:21:18 ubuntu4 Keepalived_vrrp[13361]: (Line 40) Unknown configuration entry 'lable' for ip address ->
Feb 01 17:21:18 ubuntu4 Keepalived_vrrp[13361]: (Line 40) Unknown configuration entry 'eth0:vip' for ip addres>
Feb 01 17:21:18 ubuntu4 Keepalived_vrrp[13361]: (VI_1) State MASTER must match being address owner
Feb 01 17:21:18 ubuntu4 Keepalived_vrrp[13361]: (VI_1) Strict mode does not support authentication. Ignoring.
Feb 01 17:21:18 ubuntu4 Keepalived_vrrp[13361]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
Feb 01 17:21:18 ubuntu4 Keepalived_vrrp[13361]: (VI_1) Entering BACKUP STATE (init)
Feb 01 17:21:22 ubuntu4 Keepalived_vrrp[13361]: (VI_1) Entering MASTER STATE
```

I hope this helps someone.  I will reach out to: Copyright(C) 2001-2019 Alexandre Cassen, acassen@gmail.com
on github.